# Kong DB-less in Docker

Tags: docker, kong

As of Kong 1.1 you can use db-less (declarative) configuration.

I can't find any information on how to start a Kong 1.1 based container in db-less/declarative mode without having to set up a db connection first. Does anyone know how to do this?

Checks documentation at https://hub.docker.com/_/kong

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On the step 4 of [kong official docker installation](https://docs.konghq.com/install/docker/), 
just change the config of docker run command FROM ***-e "KONG_DATABASE=postgres"*** TO ***-e "KONG_DATABASE=off"*** and you can go ahead!

*remember that if you have a kong container run with postgres or cassandra before, firstly remove that configured kong container and image! Then run command like above*

References:
[kong database less configuration](https://docs.konghq.com/1.1.x/db-less-and-declarative-config/#setting-up-kong-in-db-less-mode): this shows the way to config database less by "off"
[kong docker compose file](https://github.com/Kong/docker-kong/blob/11b9baa1e58ddc7e0e494b8b5e7efc44bdf57da8/compose/docker-compose.yml#L37): this shows the config of kong database in docker